# Некорректно срабатывает js (jquery) script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, который при наведении на элемент меню должен менять класс у блока с подкатегориями.

```
$('.js-menu-trigger').hover(function () {
  if(!$(this).hasClass('sub--null'))
    {
      $('.js-menu-screen').toggleClass('is-visible');
      $(this).toggleClass('sub--visible');
    }
});
```

Проблема в том, что если навести на элемент меню до того, как загрузится страница, то скрипт прописывает элементу класс, который сохраняется в html. И из за этого отображается блок, который должен быть виден только по наведении на элемент.

Comment: Как это навести на меню до того, как загрузится страница? Как вы наведёте, если страница ещё не загрузилась?

Comment: @Yuri, в момент когда прорисовалась часть html&CSS, но догружаются  скрипты и тп.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что если вы будете использовать обе функции hover, чтобы указывать конкретно, что при наведении есть класс, при отведении класса нет?

```
$('.js-menu-trigger.sub--null').hover(function () {
      $('.js-menu-screen').addClass('is-visible');
      $(this).addClass('sub--visible');
    },function () {
      $('.js-menu-screen').removeClass('is-visible');
      $(this).removeClass('sub--visible');
    }
});
```